# How to prove that if $T$ is diagonalizable and $T^3=T^2$, $T^2=T$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, inverse, diagonalization

For my linear algebra homework, I need to prove that if $T$ is a diagonalizable linear map and $T^3=T^2$, then $T^2=T$. I tried proving that $T$ is invertible (so that I can multiply both sides of $T^3=T^2$ by $T^{-1}$, but apparently diagonalizability does not imply invertibility (see [Can a matrix be invertible but not diagonalizable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2207078/can-a-matrix-be-invertible-but-not-diagonalizable) in the comment section of the first answer).

Could you help me?

Comment: This is quite simple - all you have to do is write $T = SDS^{-1}$ from definition where $D$ is a diagonal matrix. The rest is easy

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$A$ is diagonalizable and $A^3 = A^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/854275/a-is-diagonalizable-and-a3-a2) – found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24T%5E3%20%3D%20T%5E2%24%2C%20AND%20content%3Adiagonalizable)

Comment: Another approach is possible if you know the minimal polynomial for a diagonalizable matrix has no repeated roots…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $T$ is diagonalizable, then you have a diagonal matrix $D$ and an invertible matrix $P$ such that $T=PDP^{-1}$.
Now you have $$T^3=T^2$$
$$PDP^{-1}PDP^{-1}PDP^{-1}=PDP^{-1}PDP^{-1}$$

$$PD^3P^{-1}=PD^2P^{-1}%$$
$$D^3=D^2$$

Now,  you can't just apply $D^{-1}$ as that might not exist, but what is the formula entrancewise for $D^n$?    from that you should be able to conclude what $D$ has to look like and finish